# How to use foregroundStyle with NavigationLink in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I see that `foregroundColor` is being deprecated in favor of `foregroundStyle` however I'm not clear how to style text in a NavigationLink. It ignores a color in `foregroundStyle` but will adopt it in `foregroundColor`.

In this example with foregroundStyle the colors are ignored.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink {
                    
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "globe")
                        .imageScale(.large)
                        .foregroundStyle(.primary)
                    Text("Hello, world!")
                        .foregroundStyle(.primary)
                }
            }
            .padding()
        }
    }
}
```

In this example with foregroundColor the colors are adopted.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink {
                    
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "globe")
                        .imageScale(.large)
                        .foregroundColor(.primary)
                    Text("Hello, world!")
                        .foregroundColor(.primary)
                }
            }
            .padding()
        }
    }
}
```

How do you change the color of text in a `NavigationLink` with `foregroundStyle` or something other than `foregroundColor`?

Comment: `foregroundStyle`, works for me in my tests. Used `.foregroundStyle(.red)` for the Image, and
 `.foregroundStyle(.blue)` for the Text.
 On MacOS 14.3, using Xcode 15.2, tested on real ios 17 devices (not Previews) and macCatalyst. It could be different on older systems.

Comment: When it's in a NavigationLink these styles are ignored and the accent color is applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.tint` instead:

```swift
NavigationLink {

} label: {
    Image(systemName: "globe")
        .imageScale(.large)
        .tint(.primary)
    Text("Hello, world!")
        .tint(.primary)
}
```